# Plotting a basic vectorized function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to get my function to plot a vectorized function over a python list interval and having a `name`/`title` for the graph. I am fairly new to python packages like numpy and matplotlib. I hope someone can shed some light on my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline    

def test_plot(x,interval,title):
    x = np.vectorize(x)
    interval = [0,interval+1]
    ttl = plt.title(title)
    plt.plot(x,interval)
    return plt.plot(x,interval)    

test_plot([-1,0,1,2,3,4],2,'test')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Note: I need the `interval` to be a `list`.

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) ?

Comment: Your x-coordinates (-1 through 4) have 6 elements in the set. Your y-coordinates only have two because of this line: `interval = [0,interval]` Now if you run that in the Python interpreter you get something like this: `interval = 2` (defined in your input to the function), `interval = [0,interval+1]` (specified in your function), which leaves your y-coordinates with only 0 and 3 to work with (check the value of `interval` in your python interpreter to verify this). The poor code can then pair only the first two elements of the x and y coordinates.

Comment: Why are you `vectorize`ing a list?

Comment: @fjarri i'm trying to vectorize a function.

Comment: @fjarri good question. OP: I don't see the need for numpy in your code. You can save a bit of time by not importing it. Just think about *why* you want to put anything in your code before doing it. ;)

Comment: @FredBarclay I probably don't know what I'm doing then. I'm trying to have my function take a vectorized function over an interval (that must be a list) then plot it.

Comment: hi @misheeoh. First of all--I'm a newbie too so take my "help" with a grain of salt, lol. :D But what do you mean by a "vectorised function"? Do you mean a list by chance, not a function?

Comment: @FredBarclay yes, looking to take a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like KIDJournety, I don't quite understand what you're wanting either, but if I understand your comments correctly this might work:

`def test_plot(x, interval, title):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.title(title)
    plt.plot(x, interval)
    plt.show()`

`test_plot([1,2,3], [7,6,5], "hello, world!")` works well. 
If this doesn't do what you need (what with the vectorisation) please comment below and I'll do my best to adjust the code accordingly.

Now for some practical reasons why your original code did not work:
You were passing a list or vector with 6 elements (-1 through 4) as the x-values of the graph, but only 2 elements(0 and interval+1, which was 3 in your example) as your y-values. Your poor code could only pair (-1, 0) and (0,3). The rest of the x-coordinates had no corresponding y-coordinates to be paired to, so the code failed.

Comment: Well, I thank you for your effort. The question just states to define a function that takes a vectorized function and a python list interval of length 2 and have a title on it. I think what you gave is suitable. Sorry for the confusion !!

Comment: @misheekoh homework or self-studying? Sometimes we newbies get confused by stuff like this. :) Keep learning and it'll get easier! BTW: if this or KIDJourney's answer solved your trouble, would you be so kind as to accept the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: Homework + studying. But I understand now. thank you. I can't accept @KIDJourney's answer. I will probably delete this bad question. thank you again

Comment: @misheekho: I can't tell you what to do with your own question, of course, but I wouldn't delete if I were you. It's valuable for anyone else who makes the same mistake. Trust me, we've all been there! :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are going to plot.

After checking the document , you can find :

[numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) requires a pyfunc to be 
initialized .

For example :

```
>>> def myfunc(a, b):
...     "Return a-b if a>b, otherwise return a+b"
...     if a > b:
...         return a - b
...     else:
...         return a + b
```

Then initiate your vectorize function

```
>>>vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
>>>vfunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
array([3, 4, 1, 2])
```

The parameter pyfunc must be **callable** . Passing a list seems meaningless .

As for [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

This function require x and y to have same dimension to be plotted .

But what your pass is a function and two elements list causing a **ValueError**